# Как скопировать из dataGridView элементы в динамический массив изначально не задавая количество элементов массива?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
class one //класс хранящий массив
{
    public double[] intArray = new double[0];
}
```

```
one One = new one();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //вызов 1 кнопки (считывание и запись в list из datagrid и копирование из листа в массив
{
    var _listOfTrad = new List<Double>();
    for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            _listOfTrad.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[0, a].Value));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not enough values!");
        }
    }
    _listOfTrad.CopyTo(One.intArray, 0);
}
```

Comment: При нажатии button_click1 выдает ошибку

Comment: Динамический массив - это список `List<T>`. `One.intArray = _listOfTrad.ToArray();` - будет создан новый массив, состоящий из элементов списка. Количество элементов в массиве `T[]` невозможно изменить после его создания.

Comment: @aepot Понял, благодарю. Тоесть метод ToArray() создает для массива intArray новую динамическую память - указаный из кол. элементов списка?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое динамическая память, такого термина нет в моем словаре, поэтому не смогу ответить на этот комментарий. Выше я уже написал, что оно делает, никаких секретов от вас я не скрыл.